# how to toggle italic tags inside editable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

trying to create a simple html editor
in the example below pls place cursor inside the word `lorem` and click button
the word becomes italic
two questions

- is this the right way to do this ?
- how to toggle this funcionality, i.e. remove `<i></i>` by clicking again ?

```js
var ed = $('#ed');
$('.btnitalic').on('click', function(){
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.modify('move', 'backward', 'word');
    sel.modify('extend', 'right', 'word');
    var str = sel.toString();
    var rn = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var tx = rn.extractContents();
    var i = document.createElement('i');
    i.appendChild(tx);
    rn.insertNode(i);
    console.clear();
    console.log(ed.html());
});
```

```css
.ed{display:inline-block; width:100%; min-height:99px; background:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btnitalic'>ITALIC</button>
<br><br>
<div class='ed' id='ed' contenteditable>
lorem ipsum
dolor sit
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest searching for existing Wysiwyg JavaScript editors and seeing how they work. You can find a complex solution but there also should be simple ones that you can inspect.

Comment: @jcubic - thanks a lot, I already tried - without success - but I believe you're right